# failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` when upgrade polkadot version to 0.9.31

Tags: polkadot, versioning

I am developing polkadot version from 0.9.25 to 0.9.31.
When I run cargo build --release, it shows

[image]

Any body has experience about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with versions, sp-core uses the parity-util-mem but there is conflict which another dependdency that is using parity-util-mem too but in a different version.

Make sure you have all dependencies in the same version.

Check the runtime/Cargo.toml and make sure all are importing from the branch `polkadot-v0.9.31` :

```
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.31" }
```

And in the Cargo.toml of your pallets too.

For more info about how to make the update to the polakdot v0.9.31 you can check this [PR](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/378a3e5ae41df1af0ef1a66b2076342bce678688) that updates it in the Substrate Node Template.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to dependencies, you have to use the same dependency in every pallet so that there are no further conflicts.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: You are trying to update from 0.9.25 to 0.9.31, so there might be some dependencies that are being used twice with different versions, you need to check that.

Comment: Could you point me exactly where and how to check it?